# How to setup return_value for a function call with specific signature?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, patch

I have some code like this

```
class MyClass:
    def my_function(self):
        ....
        return lst
```

I want to test some other functions calling `my_function`. I can't figure out how to set the `return_value` for the call of function with specific signature. Is there any way to do that? This can be done very easily with Moq in .Net though...

This is what I tried but it doesn't work.

```
with patch("MyClass.my_function") as my_mock:
    my_mock(1, 2).return_value = [
        {
            "id" : "A"
        }
    ]

    #call the function...
    #assert...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_mock(1, 2).return_value = value
```

What you are doing with that line is actually setting the return_value for another mock object returned by call to `my_mock`. The value you've assigned there will be returned if you execute `m()()`, not `m(1, 2)` as you probably expected.

`return_value` doesn't depend on the call signature and should be used like this:

```
>>> my_mock.return_value = 'foobar'
>>> my_mock()
'foobar'
>>> my_mock(1, 2)
'foobar'
```

If you want the return value to depend on call arguments, you should use `side_effect`:

```
>>> def mock_func(*args):
...     if args == (1, 2):
...         return 'foo'
...     else:
...         return 'bar'
...
>>> my_mock.side_effect = mock_func
>>> my_mock(1, 2)
'foo'
>>> my_mock()
'bar'
```

BTW, I prefer to patch methods with [patch.object](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object). I don't think `patch("MyClass.my_function")` will work because `patch()` requires target to start with package/module name.

Comment: `patch(...)` works, it targets to the function of the loaded module instead of a specific object. But I will try the `side_effect`. Thx.